# How do I get the absolute remote actor url from inside the actor?

Tags: scala, akka

I want to do do something like this .

Actor A :

```
    actorB ! "info"

     def receive()={
     case _ => {
          println("Remote address is "+ _)

        }
}
```

Actor B : (this deployed remotely )

```
def receive()={
 case "info" => {
      sender tell self.path.address.toString

    }

}
```

I want it to return me the string akka://10.4.20.40:2555/slave/user/slaverunner . But what I get is just akka://slave. How do I get the remote host and port?  . The properties host,port and hostport on the address object dont return anything

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you call

```
sender.path.toString
```

in actor A you will get the address of the sender.  So you don't need to pass the address to another actor system as long as you can send a message to it.

Akka will not give you a remote path for an actor in the local system, which is why `self.path.address.toString` in actor B won't work.

If you really want to send the host and port from B to A then you'll need to get access to a `RemoteActorRefProvider` via the `ExtendedActorSystem`.  The official way to do that is through an [Extension](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/extending-akka.html).  For example:

```
class MyExtensionImpl(system: ExtendedActorSystem) extends Extension {
  def address = system.provider match {
    case rarp: RemoteActorRefProvider => rarp.transport.address
    case _ => system.provider.rootPath.address
  }
}

object MyExtension extends ExtensionKey[MyExtensionImpl]

val address = MyExtension(system).address
```

And that will give you the exact address that you need to communicate remotely with B.

(note this code works with Akka 2.0.x.  In 2.1.x you can avoid going through `RemoteActorRefProvider` by using `system.provider.getDefaultAddress`)

In Akka if you are using constructing actor addresses this way for use with `actorFor` then you need to make sure the hostnames match exactly.

For example if the ActorSystem thinks the host is `foo.bar.com`, then it will ignore the messages sent by a remote host to `actorFor("akka://slave@foo:2555/user/slaverunner")`

Comment: You should most definitely not do: "context.system.asInstanceOf[ExtendedActorSystem].provider.asInstanceOf[RemoteActorRefProvider].transport.address". Any and all blind casting is completely unsupported. Please read the documentation for description on how to accomplish this task, I assure you that it's in there.

Comment: Got rid of unsupported casting through `RemoteActorRefProvider` and added example for Akka 2.1.

Comment: You just traded a ClassCastException for a MatchError. What will the code do it the implementation details change?

Comment: Based on the extension system (and since I've seen so many `system.asInstanceOf[ExtendedActorSystem]` floating around) I've assumed that all actor systems will always be `ExtendedActorSystem`s.   Fair enough.

Comment: That an ActorSystem is also an ExtendedActorSystem is an implementation detail. Use the Extension SPI to obtain an ExtendedActorSystem. Cheers,

Comment: Thanks - actually it turns out that `provider.rootPath.address` gives you a local address so I had to change it to go through `RemoteActorRefProvider` again.  But I saved some code by using `ExtensionKey`.  I tested with 2.0.3.

Comment: of course root path doesn't work - "The root path for all actors within this actor system, not including any remote address information." :)

Comment: http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.1.0/#akka.actor.ActorRefProvider , see getDefaultAddress

Comment: Victor/sourcedelica, Thanks very much .  This helped !!

Answer (score 3):

**For recent akka versions (2.1+) use this:**

```
class RemoteAddressExtensionImpl(system: ExtendedActorSystem) extends Extension {
  def address = system.provider.getDefaultAddress
}

object RemoteAddressExtension extends ExtensionKey[RemoteAddressExtensionImpl]

val remoteAddr = RemoteAddressExtension(context.system).address
val remotePath = self.path.toStringWithAddress(remoteAddr))
```

the remotePath is what you were looking for:

> I want it to return me the string
>   akka://10.4.20.40:2555/slave/user/slaverunner

**For more recent akka versions (2.5.3) use this:**

```
class RemoteAddressExtensionImpl(system: ExtendedActorSystem) extends Extension {
  def address = system.provider.getDefaultAddress
}

object RemoteAddressExtension extends ExtensionId[RemoteAddressExtensionImpl]
with ExtensionIdProvider {
  override def lookup = RemoteAddressExtension
  override def createExtension(system: ExtendedActorSystem) = new RemoteAddressExtensionImpl(system)
  override def get(system: ActorSystem): RemoteAddressExtensionImpl = super.get(system)
}
```

Comment: Instead of `toStringWithAddress ` use `toSerializationFormatWithAddress`

Answer (score 1):

I got this wrapped `String`:

```
 ConfigString("akka://serversys@127.0.0.1:2552")
```

Using `system.settings`:

```
context.system.settings.config.getValue("akka.actor.deployment.\"/root\".remote")
```

Actor was a "root" actor, in a fabric scheme suggested by Viktor Klang in a mail group discussion concerning "determine if actor is dead". It was created like this:

```
lazy val rootActor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[Root], "root")
```

from `ActorSystem` that was created like this:

```
lazy val actorSystem = ActorSystem("serversys", ConfigFactory.parseString(""" 
akka {
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
  }
}
serverconf {
  include "common"
  akka {
    actor {
      deployment {
        /root {
          remote = "akka://serversys@127.0.0.1:2552"
        }    
      }
    }
    remote {
      netty {
        hostname = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 2552
      }
    }
  }
}
""").getConfig("serverconf"))
```

Tested in Scala 2.9.2 REPL with Akka 2.0.3 that I still use.

Unwrap actual value using `Config` docs here: http://typesafehub.github.com/config/v0.3.0/

Comment: Any better ideas of obtaining Global addresses could bring discussion to a new level =)

Answer (score 1):

See [public address of an actorsystem](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/akka-user/BROmkhpfHBY/discussion).
Read the full discussion, and note that "normally" you don't need to grab the host/port.

Comment: Patrik, I was trying to build a PoC , which involved slave actors registering themselves with the master.  That was my use case